# How do I import css when using @ngtools/webpack?

Tags: css, angular, webpack

I am learning angular 6 with @ngtools/webpack and I got a problem with dealing with css.

I have the following module rules in webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack' },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }
    ]
}
```

When I use Component.styleUrls, the angular compiler will use the 'raw-loader' and inline the Component.styleUrls to Component.styles. It works fine.

Then I want to install 'ngx-toastr', I added

```
import './../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css';
```

to my index.ts. It doesn't work because 'raw-loader' is used here.

How can I correctly import 'toastr.css'?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add that css to "style" in ".angular-cli.json" file it will work fine.
after adding to style it should look like this

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using angular cli

Answer (score 0):

Can you create anycomponent.scss file, import the toastr.scss file using relative file path.

import './../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css';

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. 'raw-loader' will still be used even if you import the css from scss. Btw, I already find a solution: use include & exclude rule to ensure only css in certain directories use 'raw-loader'. Not sure if It is the "correct" way, but it works.